# Compiling old VBasic Code

Tags: visual-studio-2010, compilation

So I have some external machinery that I have software for, but I want to modify the software to control the machinery better. To be more specific, the machine I have is a CNC router/milling/drilling machine and the software is the control software.

The software was provided by the manufacturer, and works fairly well, except I want to add an additional line of text to one of the screens. The manufacturer provided me with the working software (installer/exe's) plus the source code, which is stated to be VBasic. I have modified the files themselves using a plain-text editor, just need to compile it now.

The problem is that the code was originally written in around 2002. I have downloaded the latest MS Visual Studio 2013 (Ultimate?) running on a trial, all I need it for is this one job.

The files I have are:
global.bas - Seems to be mostly computer/machine connection related script
Params.frm - Parameters option screen (modified by myself)
plotter.frm - The script for the 'main' screen (the one that is always displayed)
PLOTTER.FRX (Not entirely sure what this one is for - is all in HEX/cannot be opened by MS VS)
plotter.vbp - Seems to be a main 'index' type file - links to all other files plus sets other variables
Progress.frm - The script that actually sends the command to the machine
RADIO.FRM - A minor com-port selection form

I am a PHP/JavaScript/HTML coder by nature with microprocessor experience (supposedly C++) - so i'm not new to coding - but I am completely new to VBasic/Software Programming. How do I get my files into an executable? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: sounds like you would need VB6: MS don't sell this anymore. Best bet is somewhere like Ebay....

Comment: Thankyou Mitch for your response. I have since downloaded VBasic 6.0 and had success in getting the software working how I want, but I cannot actually compile this into a usable .exe - another 'dead end'. I run windows 8 - so installing a full copy of VBasic 6.0 is not an option (believe me - I have tried!), I have also searched for third party compilers, with no success in finding one that even runs the script. More than a little lost!